# Android adding views in a for loop

Tags: android, for-loop

hi i'm trying to create an list from a json feed that has a header for each date and then the content in underneath. however the json feed i have coming in arent organised in date order i have created a for loop that gets all the dates then checks for duplicates which gives me an array of dates from the feed. I then want to add a header view to my adapter for each date and i presume i then need to add another for loop to get the content under each date? problem is at the moment my header views

so my question is how can i create a list that adds header views based on a for loop and then adds other views underneath each header?

here is my function i'm running after an AsyncTask

```
public void FillData() throws JSONException{    

      ListView list = getListView();
        list.scrollTo(0, 0);
        list.setVerticalFadingEdgeEnabled(false);

           list.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

           LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE );
            View header = inflater.inflate( R.layout.homeheader, list, false);

       fixturesView = LayoutInflater.from(getBaseContext()).inflate(R.layout.fixturescell,
                 null);


       //Log.v("MyFix", "fixturesArray = " + fixturesArray);
       if(fixturesArray.length() < 1){

             TextView emptytext = (TextView) fixturesView.findViewById(R.id.TextView02);
             emptytext.setText("No Upcoming Fixtures Available");

       }else{
        try{   

            for(int t = 0; t < fixturesArray.length(); t++){
               JSONObject matchDateDict = fixturesArray.getJSONObject(t);
               String matchDate = matchDateDict.getString("matchdate");

               if(matchDatesArray.length() != 0){

                   int lm = t - 1;
                   JSONObject lastDateDict = fixturesArray.getJSONObject(lm);
                   String lastMatchDate = lastDateDict.getString("matchdate");

                   Log.v("MyFix", "lastMatchDate " + lastMatchDate);

                   if(matchDate.equals(lastMatchDate)){
                       Log.v("MyFix", "2 are the same");                        
                   } else {
                       Log.v("MyFix", "add new matchdate to array");   
                       matchDatesArray.put(matchDate);
                   }

               } else {
                   Log.v("MyFix", "add new matchdate to array (first time only)");                      
                   matchDatesArray.put(matchDate);    
               }
            }


            Log.v("MyFix", "matchDatesArray = " + matchDatesArray);

        }catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

         DateHeader = LayoutInflater.from(getBaseContext()).inflate(R.layout.redcell,
                 null);

         adapter = new MergeAdapter();

        for(int t = 0; t < matchDatesArray.length(); t++){      

          JSONObject mdheaderdict = matchDatesArray.getJSONObject(t);
           String matchheader = mdheaderdict.getString("matchdate");

               TextView matchdayheader = (TextView) DateHeader.findViewById(R.id.redheadertext);
               matchdayheader.setText(matchheader);
               adapter.addView(DateHeader);
        }               
     }     
       setListAdapter(adapter);  

}
```

heres an example of  the json feed

```
fixturesdata{"code":200,"error":null,"data":{"fixtures":[{"kickoff":"15:00:00","matchdate":"2012-07-14","homescore":null,"awayscore":null,"attendance":null,"homepens":null,"awaypens":null,"division_id":"5059","division":"Testing 1","comp":"LGE","location":null,"fixture_note":null,"hometeam_id":"64930","hometeam":"Team 1","awayteam_id":"64933","awayteam":"Team 4"},{"kickoff":"15:00:00","matchdate":"2012-07-14","homescore":null,"awayscore":null,"attendance":null,"homepens":null,"awaypens":null,"division_id":"5059","division":"Testing 1","comp":"LGE","location":null,"fixture_note":null,"hometeam_id":"64935","hometeam":"Team 6","awayteam_id":"64937","awayteam":"Team 8"},{"kickoff":"15:00:00","matchdate":"2012-07-28","homescore":null,"awayscore":null,"attendance":null,"homepens":null,"awaypens":null,"division_id":"5059","division":"Testing 1","comp":"LGE","location":null,"fixture_note":null,"hometeam_id":"64930","hometeam":"Team 1","awayteam_id":"64931","awayteam":"Team 2"},{"kickoff":"15:00:00","matchdate":"2012-07-28","homescore":null,"awayscore":null,"attendance":null,"homepens":null,"awaypens":null,"division_id":"5059","division":"Testing 1","comp":"LGE","location":null,"fixture_note":null,"hometeam_id":"64930","hometeam":"Team 1","awayteam_id":"64931","awayteam":"Team 2"}]}}
```

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: sorry so my question is how can i create a list that adds header views based on a for loop and then adds other views underneath each header?

Comment: perhaps an ExpandableListView would work?

Comment: I'd suggest searching `[android] listview with headers`. http://jsharkey.org/blog/2008/08/18/separating-lists-with-headers-in-android-09/ | http://code.google.com/p/android-amazing-listview/ | http://code.google.com/p/android-section-list/

Answer (score 0):

What you want isn't to add the views in a loop, but to make a proper ListView with Sections. I recommend that you read this tutorial which includes sample code.

[Sectioning your ListView](http://android.cyrilmottier.com/?p=440)